# Is it possible to trim number in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, plpgsql

I'm converting oracle to PostgreSQL while converting i'm getting error like
*function pg_catalog.btrim(numeric) does not exist*
I have declared **W_BEN_COUNT** as **NUMERIC**
Is it possible to trim number in PostgreSQL or only **VARCHAR** is possible

```
 IF TRIM(W_BEN_COUNT) <> '0' THEN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT BENMAST_BEN_CODE FROM BENMAST WHERE BENMAST_ENTITY_CODE =$1 AND BENMAST_CUSTOMER_CODE =$2 AND
                        BENMAST_BEN_CODE =$3'
          INTO W_BEN_NAME
          USING P_ENTITY_CODE, P_CUST_CODE, P_BEN_CODE;
      END IF;
```

Comment: `trim()` removes spaces from a string, it makes no sense to do this for a number. What problem are you trying to solve with that? If `w_ben_count` is numeric, then just use `if w_ben_count <> 0`

Comment: Did you, by any chance, mean to **TRUNC** it (instead of TRIM)?

Comment: Should you mean 007 = 7, then that already should be indistinguishable numeric values.

Comment: if w_ben_count <> 0 i tried like this its working